# How can I escape a dot in ToString()

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string phone number that I want to format:

```
string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

[..]
long fonenum;

if (Int64.TryParse(PhoneNumber, out fonenum)) {
    if (PhoneNumber.Length <= 9) {
        return fonenum.ToString("#0000.0000");
    }
    else if (PhoneNumber.Length == 10) {
        return fonenum.ToString("(00) 0000.0000");
    }
    [..]
}
```

but the "." is being confused with decimal place and outputs a floated number, that in my current culture will add the decimal place as ",":

3333-4444 -> 3333,4444

**How I force to show the dot as phone number separator?**

Sure I could just add Culture "US" and get what I want, but I don't even think it's the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape it by prepending a backslash:

```
fonenum.ToString("#0000\\.0000")
```

The backslash above is doubled because I am using a non-[verbatim](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-does-an-before-the-start-of-a-string-literal-mean.aspx) string literal.

Comment: @hvd: It needs to be, because the literal above is not verbatim. Of course a verbatim would work fine just as you say.

Comment: I read it as "It needs to be in a non-verbatim string literal", as saying that verbatim string literals wouldn't work. Re-reading now, I do see what you meant, and you're right.

Comment: I rephrased it for clarity, to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Escape it by single quotes:

```
fonenum.ToString("#0000'.'0000")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested a bit more and have found another too:

`fonenum.ToString(@"#0000\.0000")`

Related to Jon answer ("@" escapes the "\").